# Squirrel and Jasper SQL Results differ

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports

I'm working on a query in Jasper where I need to get two fields back from a database.  The query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.proto, SUM(type_count) AS count
FROM view_result a
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT photo, count(*) AS type_count
FROM load_result
GROUP BY proto) b
ON a.proto = b.proto
WHERE id IN
(SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM survey
WHERE survey.file_name IN (list of file names)
GROUP BY proto
```

This query works perfectly in Squirrel.  However, if I take what SHOULD be the same query and use it in Jasper:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.proto, SUM(type_count) AS count
FROM view_result a
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT photo, count(*) AS type_count
FROM load_result
GROUP BY proto) b
ON a.proto = b.proto
WHERE id IN
(SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM survey
WHERE ${IN, a.file_name, file_names}
GROUP BY proto
```

(Where file_names is a list of strings, just as it is in the Squirrel version),
I get a completely different set of results.  Are these queries not really equivalent?  I'm using the exact same files and everything, so I can't see a reason why this shouldn't be working.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You seem to be missing a close parenthesis on both queries (after the `in` lists). Also, you don't need distinct if using a `group by`.

Comment: I have not seen `$(IN, a.file_name, file_names)` in Jasper Reports. `$X{IN, a.file_name, file_names}` is supported.

Comment: @JohnHC I messed up there, those parenthesis are in, I missed them when copying over!

Comment: @Viki888 yes, I have that.  I'll edit, thanks for pointing it out.  That was a typo!

Answer (score 1):

First query uses `survey.file_name` in the IN clause, second one uses `a.file_name`.